# Having issue in Facebook login. In local it is working fine but in live not working

Tags: facebook

Having issue in Facebook login. In local it is working fine but in live not working. before 2-3 months before it was working in live but suddenly stop working.
At that time it was tested properly. When i googled it says some of setting is changed by facebook (Like is strict Url On).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since October 6, 2018, all apps are required to use HTTPS.

If your server don't have an SSL Certificate (e.g. the app is not served trough the https:// protocol) then you will not be able to use facebook oauth login.

If you self-host your app or your hosting service doesn't offer HTTPS by default, you can obtain a free certificate for your domain(s) from Let's Encrypt.

Please follow this guide to generate and install the certificate: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/